# jQuery Dom numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How do you get element from dom?

Comment: What do you mean by "index of an element with respect to the DOM root"? Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: You'll have to describe how you want to count.  The DOM is hierarchical, not sequential.  Do you want parents + previous siblings or previous siblings + parent + parent's previous siblings + parent's parent + parent parent's previous siblings, etc...?

Comment: In this example, what should the index of the "test" element be: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/LsfQs/

Comment: I've added a more clear description about what I'm looking for.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'd say the element's index should be 7 or 8 (depending if you include its parent element). It doesn't matter as long as I'm able to use a selector again to identify the element. I'll probably use something like $("html").find("*").eq(8)

Comment: See my answer below.  I don't think you should be using an index.  You should either just save the DOM element reference directly or attach a unique ID or class name to the element so you can find it that way.  No selector/jQuery operation that fetches and/or counts all nodes in the document is going to be fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for the universal-selector *

```
  //retrieve the index
$('*').index($('button'));
  //access the element by index
$('*:eq('+index+')');
```

Comment: Looks like this accomplishes what I'm looking for! Is this efficient enough to execute on larger pages with plenty of nodes in the DOM?

Comment: The major problem in my opinion is the fact, that the index is not a good solution to identify an element. The DOM may change, when nodes will be inserted or removed, the index will match a different element. Users may also change the DOM on their own, e.g. by using Greasemonkey-scripts or similar, so I would'nt suggest to do this.

Comment: @Rila It is not efficient at all. Use an ID or a class, they are meant for writing selectors.

Comment: This is NOT efficient at all.  It builds a giant jQuery object with references to every object in the page and then looks through it looking for a given DOM element.

Comment: That's too bad, is there anything more efficient that can do the same job? For my use case, I'm not worried about the DOM changing, because when the DOM changes the index will also change. I'm looking for a solution that can stand up even when there is no class or ID on the element. Refer to my comment on @jfriend00's post for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to uniquely identify an element in the DOM and be able to get back to the same DOM element in the future, then just save the reference to the element directly.  You don't have to get an element back via some odd selector that counts from the beginning of the document, you can just save the reference to the actual element.  For example:

```
var lastClickedItem;

$("div").click(function() {
    if (lastClickedItem) {
        $(lastClickedItem).removeClass("clicked");
        // do other things to the last clicked item
    }
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
    lastClickedItem = this;
});
```

This code saves the lastClickedItem in a global variable.  You wouldn't even have to save it in a global variable.  You could just give it a unique ID or class name and be able to retrieve the given element using that.  Counting from the front of the DOM to get back to the same element seems pretty inefficient.

Or, using a unique class name:

```
$("div").click(function() {
     $(".lastClick").removeClass("lastClick");
     $(this).addClass("lastClick");
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately my use case is a little eccentric. I need to be able to identify the DOM element when the page is loaded on a different browser at a different time. So the problem becomes, how can I **store** a unique reference to an element. My use case is similar to an A/B testing tool that would need to find an element uniquely and modify it. Thanks a lot for your continued help with this!

Comment: I give up.  We do a lot of work and ONLY now you explain what you're really trying to do.  If you can't make any modifications to the document and you can't store any element references, then count away with the inefficient mechanism.  That will be brittle against DOM changes though so I don't think you can have your cake and eat it too here.

Comment: You're right, I should have explained my intentions with more clarity. Thanks for your help with this anyways sir, it's very much appreciated.